# Digital Ocean Ubuntu SSH port number?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssh, server, digital-ocean

I am using a [Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma) on how to set up a Rails app on Ubuntu 14.04. There, I am asked to use my *customized port number*, but I haven't really customized any port numbers yet. Can someone please tell me how to figure out what port number to use?

Answer (score 1):

Your SSH will most likely run on port 22 if you didn't change the port number in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

It seems that [your tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma) refers to [another tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-14-04) on setting up Ubuntu on DO. Looking at the comments, the server setup was updated to no longer include the part where it says you should change your SSH port away from the default port 22.